# Choosing/evaluating macro argument forms

Tags: function, macros, case, common-lisp

The Common Lisp `case` macro always defaults to `eql` for testing whether its keyform matches one of the keys in its clauses. I'm aiming with the following macro to generalize `case` to use any supplied comparison function (although with evaluated keys):

```
(defmacro case-test (form test &rest clauses)
  (once-only (form test)
    `(cond ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (clause)
                         `((funcall ,test ,form ,(car clause))
                           ,@(cdr clause)))
            `,clauses))))
```

using

```
(defmacro once-only ((&rest names) &body body)
  "Ensures macro arguments only evaluate once and in order.
   Wrap around a backquoted macro expansion."
  (let ((gensyms (loop for nil in names collect (gensym))))
    `(let (,@(loop for g in gensyms collect `(,g (gensym))))
      `(let (,,@(loop for g in gensyms for n in names collect ``(,,g ,,n)))
        ,(let (,@(loop for n in names for g in gensyms collect `(,n ,g)))
           ,@body)))))
```

For example:

```
(macroexpand '(case-test (list 3 4) #'equal
                ('(1 2) 'a 'b)
                ('(3 4) 'c 'd)))
```

gives

```
(LET ((#:G527 (LIST 3 4)) (#:G528 #'EQUAL))
  (COND ((FUNCALL #:G528 #:G527 '(1 2)) 'A 'B)
        ((FUNCALL #:G528 #:G527 '(3 4)) 'C 'D)))
```

1. Is it necessary to worry about macro variable capture for a functional argument (like #'equal)? Can such arguments be left off the `once-only` list, or could there still be a potential conflict if `#'equal` were part of the keyform as well. Paul Graham in his book [On Lisp](http://www.bookshelf.jp/texi/onlisp/onlisp_10.html#SEC67), p.118, says some variable capture conflicts lead to "extremely subtle bugs", leading one to believe it might be better to `(gensym)` everything.
2. Is it more flexible to pass in a test name (like `equal`) instead of a function object (like #'equal)? It looks like you could then put the name directly in function call position (instead of using `funcall`), and allow macros and special forms as well as functions?
3. Could `case-test` instead *be* a function, instead of a macro?

Comment: See also [`fcase`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/fcase.html) in CLISP.

Comment: Alexandria also has `SWITCH` for this.

Comment: This is similar to `SELECTOR` like in Lisp Machine Lisp. ca. 1980. https://common-lisp.net/svn/mit-cadr/trunk/lisp/sys2/lmmac.lisp  Though SELECTOR does not evaluate the test function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Variable capture

Yes, you need to put the function into the `once-only` because it can be created dynamically.

The extreme case would be:

```
(defun random-test ()
  (aref #(#'eq #'eql #'equal #'equalp) (random 4)))
(case-test foo (random-test)
  ...)
```

You want to make sure that the `test` is the same in the whole `case-test` form.

## Name vs. object

Evaluating the `test` argument allows for very flexible forms like

```
(case-test foo (object-test foo)
  ...)
```

which allows "object-oriented" `case-test`.

## Function vs. macro

Making `case-test` into a function is akin to making any other conditional (`if` and `cond`) into a function - how would you handle the proverbial

```
(case-test "a" #'string-equal
  ("A" (print "safe"))
  ("b" (launch missiles)))
```